# Is the sentence "Each of my brothers wants his own car" correct?

Tags: pronouns, plural-forms, singular

> Each of my brothers wants his own car

I already know that each is always paired with singular but is the usage of "his" correct? Should it be "their" or "it"?

Comment: My brothers want their own car. Each brother wants his own car.  O seu próprio carro.

Comment: Yeah, not being able to say "seu" in the sentence got me confused because we don't have to involve gender in portuguese and the genderless pronoun would be "their" but that doesn't match in terms of number...

Comment: their is not necessarily genderless: The ladies wore their  best outfits to the party. The men wore their best outfits to the party. their is for men or women or the new pronoun they. They wore (new pronoun) their best outfit to the party. Mas claro, acaba sendo uma bagunça esse uso de their.

Comment: Oh thank you for the clarification!

Comment: O meu gato se chama Coco Leticia. :) Adoro esse nome.

Comment: Entendi! Eu ficava bem confusa, mas acho que estou entendo melhor agora.
Que fofura! :) As in "Coco Chanel"?

Comment: Exatamente isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is correct.

"Each" is indeed a singular pronoun, so the singular "his" is correct.

"Their" is naturally used about people when the sex is unclear:

> Each of my **siblings** wants **their** own car.

It's becoming more common to use "their" when the sex is clear, as in your example sentence, but some will still insist on using "their" only when the sex is unclear. So in daily life, "his" or "their" are both fine, but in class, or for an assignment or exam, use the singular as much as you can.

"It" isn't the right part of speech at all. "Its" is the correct part of speech, but is incorrect because brothers are people, and "its" only refers to non-humans.

Comment: If you had siblings of more than one gender, you could say 'each of my siblings wants his or her own car', but some people would find it awkward or objectionable for one reason or another.

Comment: Oooh thank you so much!
If the sentence was "each of them" instead of "each of my brothers", would it still be correct to say "his" (considering that the people in the conversation know that "them" refers to the brothers)?

Comment: @LetíciaVasconcellosAlves As long as it's clear from the context that "them" refers to your brothers (or some group of males), then yes, "his" would still be correct